# OpsWorks Chef 11.10 undefined method 'property'

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef, opsworks, berkshelf

Chef 11.10 ran fine until we resized an instance, now setup_failed on boot with log:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `property' for #<Class:0x007f7c97afc100>


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/windows/resources/auto_run.rb:22:in `class_from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/windows/resources/auto_run.rb:

21:  
22>> property :program_name, String, name_property: true
23:  property :path, String, coerce: proc { |x| x.tr('/', '\\') }
24:  property :args, String
25:  property :root, Symbol,
26:           equal_to: %i(machine user),
27:           default: :machine
28:  
29:  alias_method :program, :path
30:  
31:  action :create do
```

The Berkshelf version is 3.2.0. I'm unable to SSH into the instance to get detailed logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure I answered you elsewhere but for posterity, you are trying to use a version of the windows cookbook that requires Chef 12, but you are using Chef 11. You need to restrict the cookbook version.